# Need to make a powershell script to run test-path for every line in a file, how?

Tags: powershell

I want to make a script. It will read content from a file which recorded path. And run test-path for path in the file to verify if these file/path exists on local machine.

Here is my current powershell code:

```
Foreach ($path in (get-content C:\temp\pathlist.txt)){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        path = $path
        Exists = test-path $path
    }
}
```

However, it will always return 'False' even the path exists and even there is only one line in the txt.
I also tried -TotalCount to restrict  the line it reads. But it failed again.

Besides, actually I would like to do some string process on the txt. The txt in above code just contain normal path. But the acutal txt I would got has a format as:
"C:\Windows\","1"
I used to use $path= $path.split(",")[0] to get the "C:\windows". But to fix the always 'False' issue, I use a simple txt instead and remove this part in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine. It must be something with your text formatting, I think?
Could you also share the text file you're using to test with?

My text file:

```
C:\Temp
C:\Windows
C:\NoExist
C:\Program Files
```

The code:

```
Foreach ($path in Get-Content .\test.txt) {
   [PSCustomObject]@{
        path   = $path
        Exists = Test-Path $path
   }
}
```

My output:

```
path             Exists
----             ------
C:\Temp            True
C:\Windows         True
C:\NoExist        False
C:\Program Files   True
```

**Edit after comment:**

You can split your path on " using `.split()`, example below.

New text file:

```
"C:\temp\","1"
"C:\Windows\","3"
"C:\NoExist\","1"
"C:\Program Files\","2"
```

New code:

```
Foreach ($path in Get-Content .\test.txt) {
    $path = $path.Split('"')
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        path   = $path[1]
        Exists = Test-Path $path[1]
    }
}
```

Output:

```
path              Exists
----              ------
C:\temp\           False
C:\Windows\         True
C:\NoExist\        False
C:\Program Files\   True
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your text file and it's fine for my script as well. But actually the path in my text has  double quotation mark "" as "C:\temp". I found that test-path "C:\temp"  returns true, but it return false for when I use this code. And I don't know how to split this string with "... And my origion text is like    "C:\temp\","1"      , it's output from process monitor, "1" means it occurs once, I only need path in this string..Could you help me? Thank you!

Comment: So I used path = $path.split("""")[1]  or path = $path.split("""")[-4]   for   my text ( for example,  "c:\TEMP","1"). The path in output looks correct but it return false..

Comment: Made an edit to my post showing how you can deal with the split.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your effort on this question... I don't know why but seems after a sleep my script work on my machine....Now I have some other questions but I will separate the question.  Nice experience to get your help here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me - the only thing I see is that you have a space between `for` and `each` but that may only be a typo

I used a file with both, existing and non-existing directories to test your code and it worked fine:

```
$tested_paths = foreach ($path in (Get-Content ".\paths.txt")) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        path_name   = $path
        path_exists = Test-Path $path
    }
}

$tested_paths | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes it's typo. It's my 1st question in stackoverflow, I tried paste my code but failed so I typed them manually. You can see my comment to Michael B,  I found it will fail when the path in the text within a format has double quotation marks as "C:\temp"